# javascript writing to innerHTML not working

Tags: javascript

I call the below function onblur of the "name" field as well as on press of a button. For onblur, the value to innerHTML is written fine and is displayed besides the textbox. But when I click the button, even though the function gets invoked and all the loops are working fine, the writing to innerHTML bit doesn't work. I have done my head in but can't understand what am I doing wrong?

```
function Valid(name) {
  alert("check1");
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  if (name.length < 2) {
    alert("length < 2");
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Message 1";
    return false;
  } else {
    var reg = /^[a-z]+$/i;
    if (reg.test(name.charAt(0))) {
      alert("FIrst character is alphabet");
      document.getElementById("error").style.display = "none";
    } else {
      alert("First character not alphabet");
      document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Message2";
      return false;
    }
  }
  return name;
}
```

```
<article>
  <form>
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <td><label>Name</label></td>
        <td colspan="1"><input type="text" id="name" /></td>
        <td colspan="2"><output id="error"></output></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</article>
```

Comment: Please update the question with relevant HTML....

Comment: Please post your HTML as well.

Comment: `<output>` takes `.value`, not `.innerHTML` so that probably doesn't help. Note also that you set `.style.display = "none"` but at no point do you set it to show.

Comment: What is the argument for?

Comment: @niet in that case shouldn't it have failed n both instances? It works when called voa onblur but not when called via onclick of  different button.    Nathan, i have removed that from code now. I was trying something with the function and left it there.

Comment: You are missing string closing tag in document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Message2; please replace with document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Message2";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## This is Working Code:

Bro this is the working code i hope it will help you. It is working for me.

```js
function Valid(){
    var regName = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/i;
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  if (name.toString().length < 2) {
          alert("length < 2");
          document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Message1";
            return true;
        }else{
    if(regName.test(name.charAt(0))){
        alert("FIrst character is alphabet");
        document.getElementById("error").style.display = "none";
      return true;
    }else{
      document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Message2";
      alert("First character not alphabet");
       return false;
    }
        }
}
```

```html
<article>
<form>
<table style="width:100%">    
<tr>    
<td><label>Name</label></td>
<td colspan="1"><input type="text" id="name" onkeyup="Valid()"/></td>
<td colspan="2"><output id="error"></output></td>
</tr>
</table></form></article>
```